# String to access nested value from object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

I have a somewhat strange question,
I would like to know if it is possible to use a string as an entire reference to get a value from an object within an array.

This is my array:

```
const myArray = [
    {name: 'element1', id: 'elementid1'},
    {name: 'element2', id: 'elementid2'}
];
```

where `myArray[0]["name"]` returns: 'element1'

Would it be possible to have this entire reference: `myArray[0]["name"]` as a string: 'myArray[0]["name"]' and use it to reference to this value.

So this: `getViaString` returns 'element1' with the following set up:

```
const getViaString = 'myArray[0]["name"]';
```

I have set up this fiddle as it probably explains better what I am trying to do:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s04b2hxg/1/)

Thanks.

Comment: `eval(getViaString)`

Comment: you had everything right, but you put quotes around your value. just do `const getViaString = myArray[0]["name"];`

Comment: @StevenStark if those quotes would be remove it would no longer be a string :(

Comment: well then you need the eval that others are recommending, but  this is a bad way to design your application and is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use `eval()` - not recommended.

```
const getViaString = eval("myArray[0]['name']");
```

Comment: If eval is not recommended, what other approach is there in this specific case?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it with

```
const getViaString = eval('myArray[0]["name"]');
```